# Email SMTP configuration for MegaRaid controller notifications

Tags: email, notifications, megaraid

I have a DELL host with XenServer. Unfortunately died my Linux administrator months ago and he did not provide any information regarding the configuration for the RAID controller.

What I know is that he set up his Exchange as the SMTP server. But his company was closed and now the SMTP Server is not accessible.

In `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` there is not any valid SMTP setting therefore I assume the RAID controller software has their own settings.

**Info:**

1. The RAID controller is LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 9271-8i
2. Under `/etc/cron.d/raid-check` I see the cron job which checks the raid status. But this does not really help me.

**My question:**
Does anybody know where I have to change the Email/SMTP settings for the MegaRaid controller software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of investigation I could fix the problem:

My administrator set up the email alerts from his own server where the Windows version of MegaRAID Storage Manager was installed.

Due to the fact I upgraded my XenServer from 6.2 to 6.5 the previous installed MegaRAID Storage Manager version of the Linux copy disappeared. Therefore I could not find anything.

I installed the Linux and Windows version and now I can set up the email address for the alerts.

Answer (score 0):

LSI offer a control panel system for their MegaRAID SAS cards - `megasasctl`.

http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS

> megaraidsas-status is a wrapper script around megactl with periodics
>   checks.  It is available in the packages repository too.
>
> The packages comes with a python wrapper around megasasctl and an
>   initscript that periodic run this wrapper to check status.  It keeps a
>   file with latest status and thus is able to detect RAID status changes
>   and/or brokeness.  It will log a ligne to syslog when something failed
>   and will send you a mail.  Until arrays are healthy again a reminder
>   will be sent each 2 hours.

Comment: There is no `megasasctl` nor `megactl` on the XenServer host system. The link you provided does not offer any download. Can it be it has not been installed while the RAID controller drivers have been installed?

Comment: Entirely possible as drivers and application are often separate...

Comment: OK, but the email settings must be somewhere as - while my administrator  lived - he sent me a test email. Usually under Linux all settings are in some configuration files but I was "grepping" for some possible values/names but I couldn't find anything.